# How to disable multiple check-out on TFS Preview with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: tfs, beta, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I have a project in TFS Preview and added 2 other guys to work on the project with Visual Studio 2012 beta. I changed the settings of the project to NOT allow multiple-checkout to files, but it doesnt change anything. I changed to work just on the server too but multiple check-outs are still allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using local workspaces in Visual Studio 2012?  This is the new default, allowing you to use workspaces that do not require read-only files, and do not require notifying the server when you check-out a file.

In order for automatic locking to work, you need to be using server workspaces.  Everyone on your team will need to convert their workspace type.  If you open Source Control Explorer, you should see your workspace name selected in a combo box in the view's toolbar.  If you drop that combo down, there will be an option: "Workspaces...".  If you then select your workspace, select "Edit", then select the "Advanced" option on the Edit Workspace dialog, you should see the option to switch the type of workspace:

If you change the workspace to "Location: Server", then you will have the same type of workspaces as with previous versions of TFS which allow automatic locking.